# How can i authenticate jbpm 7.24 with keycloak

Tags: keycloak, jbpm

i try to authenticate and autorize jbpm 7.24 via keycloak and i am following the 
http://blog.athico.com/2016/03/keycloak-sso-integration-into-jbpm-and.html
as well as the keycloak documentation for jboss.

I can't get it working. I always get errors with the kid/wrong public key/wrong secret key. I tried with many combinations for the Key RSA256 ...

```
ERROR [org.keycloak.adapters.rotation.AdapterTokenVerifier] (default task-1) Didn't find publicKey for kid
```

or

```
 ERROR [org.keycloak.adapters.OAuthRequestAuthenticator] (default task-3) failed verification of token: Secret key not set
and alike
```

Comment: You use configure client secret properly?

Comment: I think so, created i keycloak client as this is installationxml for jboss

<secure-deployment name="WAR MODULE NAME.war">
    <realm>Reach4</realm>
    <auth-server-url>https://myurl.de/auth</auth-server-url>
    <ssl-required>NONE</ssl-required>
    <resource>local_kie</resource>
    <verify-token-audience>true</verify-token-audience>
    <credential name="secret">xxxxxxxxxx</credential>
    <use-resource-role-mappings>true</use-resource-role-mappings>
</secure-deployment>

I used it in standalone_full.xml

Comment: @Thomas Did you solve the issue? Please add the right solution or mark the answer if it helped you :)

Comment: No, i was not able to solve the issue. I had also other issues with user management, like restarting jbpm after change of passwords and deploying a workflow from workbench to kie-server.

Answer (score 0):

The secret is in client created in the new Realm, as in picture 
[image]

You should click Regenerate Secret just to be sure you got the right one.